# The Number of Increasing Vectors $(x_1,...,x_k)$ Satisfying $1 \leq x_i \leq n$ and $x_1 < x_2 <...<x_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I want to find the number of increasing vectors $(x_1,...,x_k)$ satisfying $1 \leq x_i \leq n$ and $x_1 < x_2 <...<x_k$.

---

**Examples of vectors satisfying these conditions**

Let $n =5$ and $k=3$

$$(\_,\_,x_1,x_2,x_3)$$

$$(\_,x_1,\_,x_2,x_3)$$

$$(x_1,\_,x_2,\_,x_3)$$

$$(x_1,\_,x_2,x_3,\_)$$

where the spaces of the vector all numbered as follows, $$(1\,\,\,,2\,\,\,,3\,\,\,,4\,\,\,,5)$$

and in general $$(1,2,...,n)$$

---

**My Approach**

We will count the number of vectors $\underrightarrow{x}$ with components $\underrightarrow{x} = (x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ with $ 1\leq x_i\leq n$.

---

- **Implied Restriction On $x_1$**

  - The largest value $x_1$ can have is $n-k+1$.
  - The smallest value $x_1$ can have is $1$.

---

- **The Procedure**

  Count the number of different vectors $\underrightarrow{x}$ such that $\{x_1\in \mathbb{Z}: 1 \leq x_1 \leq n-k+1\}$

  Each of those vectors $\underrightarrow{x}$ has $n-x_1\choose k-1$ different increasing vectors. That is, $n-x_1$ different positions available to the $k-1$ vectors.

---

- **The Result**

  The number of increasing vectors $\underrightarrow{x}$ with $(x_1,...,x_k)$ satisfying $1 \leq x_i \leq n$ and $x_1 < x_2 <...<x_k$ is equal to 
  $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t = n-k+1} {n-i\choose k-1} = {n-1\choose k-1} + {n-2\choose k-1}  + \cdot\cdot\cdot + {n-(n-k+1)\choose k-1}$$

  or in a neater form, the total number of increasing vectors is equal to

  $$\sum\limits_{i=k-1}^{n-1} {i\choose k-1}$$

---

**Edit After Reading More Material**

$$\sum\limits_{i=k-1}^{n-1} {i\choose k-1} = \sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} {i-1\choose k-1} = {n\choose k}$$

This $$\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} {i-1\choose k-1} = {n\choose k}$$ is knows as Fermat's Combinatorial Identity.

---

**Please have a look at my solution and give any suggestions and hints you may have**.

Comment: I've not seen any specification what _kind_ values the $x_i$ are supposed to be. But given that vectors live in a vector space (which must be defined over a field) and that comparison between them is possible, they must live in  in ordered field, so at least rational numbers are allowed. Then there are infinitely many such vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is MUCH easier than all of that:

Choosing a vector with these conditions is the exactly the same than choosing a subset of the set $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$ with $k$ elements, because the only thing that you must decide for each element is whether it is in the vector/subset or it is not. The only condition is that you must choose $k$ elements.

So the answer is simply
$$\binom{n}{k}$$

Nevertheless I think that your approach is correct. And you have proved that
$$\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1}\binom{i}{k-1}=\binom{n}{k}$$
which is a well-known formula.

In Tartaglia's (or Pascal's) triangle, that means that if you sum the $k-1$ first numbers of a NE-SW diagonal, the result is the number that is just at the right of the next number in that diagonal. See red and blue drawings in the figure.

[image]

Comment: Laughing at myself for not thinking of $n\choose k$. Was not aware of such an identity, only started doing elementary combinatorics, so I'm thrilled to have coincidentally proved something. I'm not following what you're saying in the last sentence, I am lost in the words, can you link me to an example of that, please?

Comment: I hope this illustration helps :)

Comment: That's nice, I never knew that. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: I just came across an exercise asking for a proof of Fermat's Combinatorial Identity, $\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} {i-1\choose k-1} = {n\choose k}$, and coincidentally I came across this solution  when I posted this question. Just thought it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is just note that any subset of size $k$ from $1,2,\ldots, n$ corresponds to an increasing sequence uniquely by just putting the elements in order. So you have ${n\choose k}$ such subsets, hence the same number of increasing sequences.

Comment: Laughing at myself for not thinking of $n\choose k$.

Comment: "an increasing sequence uniquely" is actually the trick here. I did not think of this.